# TypeError: Joomla.JText._ is not a function

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm trying to add language translations to my js files. So I've added this code to my view.html.php file in my component:

```
JText::script('COM_TEST_ENTER_LABEL');
```

If I look at the html source I now see this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var strings = {"COM_TEST_ENTER_LABEL":"Enter a label"};
      if (typeof Joomla == 'undefined') {
        Joomla = {};
        Joomla.JText = strings;
      }
      else {
        Joomla.JText.load(strings);
      }
    })();
  </script>
```

Now I try to add this to my js file:

```
alert(Joomla.JText._('COM_TEST_ENTER_LABEL'));
```

But I just get the error in firebug: `TypeError: Joomla.JText._ is not a function`

I'm wondering if it has something to do with jQuery. I have a bunch of jquery scripts in the code (view.html.php) that are added **after**:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.migrate/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/components/com_test/js/cam.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/js/jquery.noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you look at the html source this is **before** the `JText::script` stuff. Not sure if that is the cause? If it is I'm not sure what I can do about it? Joomla is ordering this by itself as my code tried to put it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Joomla.JText._` is a MooTools based function, so you'll need to allow MooTools to load in your template (if you're removing it, a lot of folks do).

Answer (score 1):

You can access the strings using the following notation code.

alert(Joomla.JText.strings.COM_TEST_ENTER_LABEL);

This looks up the string COM_TEST_ENTER_LABEL in the string property of the JText property of the Joomla object.

Note that JText::_ is a PHP function.

Hope that helps..

Comment: I thought `JText::_` was a js function based on this [article](http://www.joomla-wiki.de/dokumentation/Benutzer:Elkuku/Proyektz/EasyCreator/Language_handling/Javascript_translations)? I did try as you suggested but I now get `TypeError: Joomla.JText.strings is undefined`

Comment: Ah, okay. I have used the code I posted before to access a string in that way but didn't realise you could do it other ways as well.
Perhaps the scripts are not being loaded in the correct order as you suggest. What code are you using to load the script? Try something like:
    $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "/components/com_test/js/cam.js",'text/javascript',true, false);

Which will add the defer arrtibute. This will defer the loading of your script. That might do the trick...

Comment: Well it seems none of the ways are working for me =\ Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try doing alert(Joomla.JText.strings.COM_TEST_ENTER_LABEL); directly in the firebug console line. You should get an alert. If not then your scripts are loading properly.

Comment: Right, I don't think they are getting loaded properly, hence the question. I tried as you suggested and get `TypeError: Joomla.JText.strings is undefined`. No luck.